# 3D Transform Card Flip Animation not working for chrome

Tags: html, css

I am using [CSS 3D Transform Card Flip Animation](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/css3dflip/). It was working fine on all browsers but it stoped working on chrome now. The 3D effect is not working now.

CSS:

```
.thumb.flip {
    -webkit-perspective:800px;
       -moz-perspective:800px;
        -ms-perspective:800px;
         -o-perspective:800px;
            perspective:800px;
}

.thumb.flip .thumb-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
       -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
        -ms-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
         -o-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
            transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
         -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.thumb.flip .thumb-detail {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
         -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
            transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.thumb.flip img, .thumb.flip .thumb-detail {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
       -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
         -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.thumb.flip .flipIt {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
         -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
            transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong or why this stoped working? Thanks

Here is the working link in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adi145/stdx17ua/)

Comment: Please provide your HTML & CSS etc in a JSfiddle.net demo.

Comment: @Paulie_D i have added the link for JSfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/adi145/stdx17ua/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this css:

```
.thumb.flip .thumb-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
       -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
        -ms-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
         -o-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
            transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
         -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

With :

```
.thumb.flip .thumb-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition: transform 1s; //Changed
       -moz-transition: transform 1s; //Changed 
        -ms-transition: transform 1s; //Changed
         -o-transition: transform 1s;//Changed
            transition: transform 1s; // Changed
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
         -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```